# How to make the navbar vertically bigger (weebly)?

Tags: html, css, navbar, weebly

I need to clarify that I have close to no understanding of pragramming so my apology if my question sounds dumb.

So the question is that I would like to make the navigation bar of my website bigger (vertically) as it looks too small right now.

Below is the code that probably should affect the change. If you need more information then I will do my best to provide that! Thanks all!

```
#nav-wrap {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-top: 3px solid #000B5C; /* #ActiveSectionColor; this one controls the top border old #199ad0; old nav color */
background: rgb(29,62,143); /* #MenuBarColor; Hex code: #1d3e8f */
background: rgba(29,62,143,1); /* #MenuBarColor; This line controls opacity. #1d3e8f, */
z-index: 999;
}

#nav-wrap .container {
clear: both;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul {
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
float: right;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li {
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin-right: 17px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul span:last-child li,
#nav-wrap .container ul > li:last-child {
background: none;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li a {
float: left;
display: block;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
padding: 14px 12px;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#nav-wrap .container ul li#active a,
#nav-wrap .container ul li a:hover {
color: #fff; /* April 2017 */
background: #000B5C; /* #ActiveSectionColor; this one controls the rest. old #199ad0; */
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, put the html.

Comment: Hi! Could you elaborate what you mean with put the html? Thank you :)

Comment: Can you provide the public link of your page?

Answer (score 0):

make css class and use these properties and call this class on your navbar tags or div tags which you are using

```
.sizing{

padding-top: 50px;
padding-bottom : 50px;
}
```

if you want sizing to vise versa then insted  of top and bottom just use right and left

Comment: Thanks so much for taking your time! As mentioned, I have close to zero understanding in regards to programming. So could you possibly tell me where I should include the text you've written down for me? Thank you!

Comment: yes put this code in <style> tags of your web .. and call sizing on your heading tag . like   <h1 class="sizing"> hello </h1>